# Remover elemento dentro de iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Olá

Tenho um Iframe que possui uma imagem e gostaria de removê-la, mas não está dando certo...

```
<script>
  $( document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).find("img[src='/assets/online/cf_logo-9733d198a764182fc89bc38518f73f91efd7a413394b1ca263e8ba4774ed8b5b.png']").hide();

  });
</script>
```

Se eu inspecionar a imagem e colar a linha do .hide() no console, ela se oculta. Se eu não inspecionar a imagem e colar, nada acontece, bem como quando eu carrego a página

Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte maneira.
Coloquei um setTimeOut para ficar mais visivel

```js
setTimeout(function(){ $("img[src='/assets/online/cf_logo-9733d198a764182fc89bc38518f73f91efd7a413394b1ca263e8ba4774ed8b5b.png']").hide();; }, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='/assets/online/cf_logo-9733d198a764182fc89bc38518f73f91efd7a413394b1ca263e8ba4774ed8b5b.png'/>
```

Comment: Ainda está do mesmo jeito... :(

Comment: Se a imagem muda de src tente pegar por xpath ou poste o html do iframe para que eu te ajude melhor